# Use of ShowDropDownOnTextboxClick property

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik

Can anybody tell what is the use of ShowDropDownOnTextboxClick property in C#?

Comment: can you give example of this property ?

Comment: What example do you need other than the proper meaning? It is just a property and it cannot be acted as an example.:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question means. But You are using Telerik RadCombo box and because that property belong to that only.

It is used to determine show dropdown when user click on input field. If you make is true then it will show dropdown when user click on input field. There are multiple way to use Telerik Rad Combox and that's why this property has given.

For more information see the official telerik documentation.

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/p_telerik_web_ui_radcombobox_showdropdownontextboxclick.html

For example If wee need to use telerik radcombobox as Autocomplete then we we have to make it false as we don't want to see dropdown and instead of that we want autocomplete.

See example where its disabled.

http://tekality.com/net/telerik-asp-net-restrict-radcomboboxs-loadondemand/

Hope this helps you!